# Как разбить текст на 2 колонки с помощью div при отображении на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css, netcat

Добрый день, всем! Как разбить div на 2 diva с текстом в виде колонок без использования Bootstrap, при этом чтобы колонки не сдвигались при отображении на мобильных устройствах?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  background: silver;
  counter-increment: i;
  
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -moz-page-break-inside:avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

body {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  counter-reset: i 0;
}

div:before {
  content: "#" counter(i) " - " attr(style);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:10em"></div>
<div style="height:1em"></div>
<div style="height:4em"></div>
<div style="height:16em"></div>
<div style="height:2em"></div>
<div style="height:5em"></div>
<div style="height:7em"></div>
<div style="height:12em"></div>
<div style="height:11em"></div>
<div style="height:3em"></div>
```